# Create BuyMeACoffee Component for Gatsby JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to create a Buy Me A Coffee React component for my Gatsby website and even though my Gatsby site runs in development mode and successfully builds, the component (Buy Me A Coffee widget) doesn't show up when loading the page.

My website uses MDX, so ideally I'd like to be able to import the component into my blog posts. I like the idea of importing it into my blog posts because it allows me to optionally include it, whereas if I use a standard solution like gatsby-ssr.js for including the third party Buy Me A Coffee script, I foresee it being much more difficult to regulate on what pages the component does and doesn't show.

At the moment, I use the library browser-monads so I don't have to do `typeof !== "undefined"` conditional check for building my site. Using the traditional conditional format they recommend here doesn't help. Also styles.scss is currently empty. I am importing this in case I need to go back and add styles to my component later.

Thanks for your help!

Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles.scss'
import { window, document, exists } from 'browser-monads';

class BuyMeACoffee extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        let script = document.createElement("script");
            script.setAttribute('data-name','BMC-Widget')
            script.src = "https://cdnjs.buymeacoffee.com/1.0.0/widget.prod.min.js"
            script.setAttribute('data-id', 'x');
            script.setAttribute('data-description', 'Thank you for your support!');
            script.setAttribute('data-message', "We're proudly reader-supported! If our content helps you, we would be honored and greatly appreciate it if you'd consider buying us a coffee!");
            script.setAttribute('data-color',"#2962ff")
            script.setAttribute('data-position','right')
            script.setAttribute('data-x_margin','18')
            script.setAttribute('data-y-margin','18')
            script.async = true
            //Call window on load to show the image
            script.onload=function(){
                var evt = document.createEvent('Event');  
                evt.initEvent('load', false, false);  
                window.dispatchEvent(evt);
            }
        this.script=script
    }

    componentDidMount () {    
        document.head.appendChild(this.script)
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        document.head.removeChild(this.script);
        document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("bmc-wbtn"))
     }

    render(){
        return(null)
    }
}

export default LoadBuyMeACoffee;
```

Comment: I noticed I forgot to update my export name `export default LoadBuyMeACoffee;
`

Updating it to be `export default BuyMeACoffee;` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `gatsby-ssr.js` approach instead of adding a load performance directly in the class component. Something like this should work for you:

```
const React = require("react");

exports.onRenderBody = ({ setPostBodyComponents }) => {
  setPostBodyComponents([
    <script
      data-name="Mac-Mann-Widget"
      src="https://cdn.buymeacoffee.com/widget/1.0.0/prod/widget.prod.min.js"
      data-id="eshlox"
      data-description="Support me on Buy me a coffee!"
      data-message="Thank you for visiting. You can now buy me a coffee!"
      data-color="#FF813F"
      data-position="right"
      data-x_margin="28"
      data-y_margin="18"
    ></script>,
  ]);
};
```

I will leave the snippet above to see if it helps someone.

---

> Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I really don't want to use
> gatsby-ssr.js because I want the ability to be able to optionally
> include the Buy Me A Coffee script in my blog posts. – Mac-Mann 4
> hours ago

You can try something like this:

- Create a function that will render asynchrounously on-demand the script:

  ```
  const addExternalScript = (url, callback) => {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = url;
      script.async=true;
      script.onload = callback;
      // add as many parameters as you need.
      document.body.appendChild(script);
  };
  ```

  You can also remove the `callback` function parameter if you don't need it despite being useful.
- Call them in your `componentDidMount()` (that will make the trick since you need to wait for the DOM tree loading until access to a `document` global object):

  ```
  componentDidMount(){
    addExternalScript(`https://cdn.buymeacoffee.com/widget/1.0.0/prod/widget.prod.min.js`)
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I really don't want to use gatsby-ssr.js because I want the ability to be able to optionally include the Buy Me A Coffee script in my blog posts.

Comment: I've updated the question with a new trial @Mac-Mann